# get value of dropdownlist before refresh MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, onchange, html-select

I just started MVC3 a week ago and i'm currently stomped, I have a prepopulated dropdownlist but I want to get the selected value of the dropdownlist before the HTTPpost or preferably each time someone chooses a different option on the list to show it .

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MyList",(object)@ViewBag.chosen)
You have chosen (object)@ViewBag.chosen
```

Comment: What are you asking? That's not a very meaningful code sample.

Comment: Well Basically the DropdownList "MyList" is prepopulated with options upon selecting an option I would like to show that selected option right underneath the dropdownlist, in the code above I tried to put "mylist" into a ViewBag to display the selected option value but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#MyList").on("change", function () {
          $("#MyList").after("You have chosen " + $("#MyList").val());
      });
  });
```